# Store session and data received with socketio

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, data-structures, socket.io

I need to store information about connections on my server.
This should store 4 connections of 4 different clients.
My clients send information like this:

```
 "0#0.0 0.0 766.5#3#0.0#"
```

In the server I assigned an id, and `show socket.broadcast.emit('message', map)` shows this:

```
message : {"id":"data"}
```

The console shows:

```
message : {"/#DVWkJsrfHFB21XUkAAAC":"0#0.0 0.0 766.5#3#0.0#"}
```

All this is stored in an object map.
Now I don't need the id, just the data `"0#0.0 0.0 766.5#3#0.0#"`.

I tried to implement this:

```
var result = "";
for(var a in map){
 result = result + map[a];
}
```

But that doesn't work right, it obtains:

```
"0#0.0 0.0 766.5#3#0.0#"
"0#0.0 0.0 766.5#3#0.0#0#0.0 0.0 766.5#3#0.0#"
"0#0.0 0.0 766.5#3#0.0#0#0.0 0.0 766.5#3#0.0#0#0.0 0.0 766.5#3#0.0#"
```

This should be showing 4 connections of 4 different clients. This is the real challenge. If I have 4 connections, I just need to show one string, with the data of the 4 connections in a single chain of objects.

This is data that I want:

```
{"data client 1", "data client 2","data client 3","data client 4"}
```

How I see in the server, this should be:

```
{"0#0.0 0.0 3593.0#3#0.0#", "0#0.0 0.0 3593.0#3#0.0#","0#0.0 0.0 3593.0#3#0.0#","0#0.0 0.0 3593.0#3#0.0#"}
```

This is the code that I am using:

```
var map = {};
var result = "";
function storeInfo(event, value){
    map[event]= value;
}
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    var clientPlayer = null;
    socket.on('message', function(data) {
        var sessionid = socket.id;
        if(sessionid in map){
            map[sessionid] = data;
            for(var a in map){
                result = result + map[a];
                // show bucle infinite
            }
            socket.broadcast.emit('message', map);
        } else {
            storeInfo(sessionid, data);
        }
        socket.emit('message', data);
    });
});
```

Comment: yes i want {"0#0.0 0.0 3593.0#3#0.0#", "0#0.0 0.0 3593.0#3#0.0#","0#0.0 0.0 3593.0#3#0.0#","0#0.0 0.0 3593.0#3#0.0#"} of 4 clients differents

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after of this night of work this is the solution:

```
var map = {};
function storeInfo(event, value){
    map[event]= value;
} 
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
        var clientPlayer = null;
        socket.on('message', function(data) {
            var sessionid = socket.id;
            if(sessionid in map){
                map[sessionid] = data;
                var result = [];
                for(var o in map){
                    result.push(map[o]);
                }
                result.join(" ");
                socket.broadcast.emit('message', result);
            } else {
                storeInfo(sessionid, data);
            }
            socket.emit('message', data);
        });
});
```